# Estimate corner points around a given point on a point cloud in 3D

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am trying to estimate the four corner of a rectangular frame, with known height and width, on a point cloud. The user selects a point on the point cloud based on which the four corners of the rectangle are to be estimated. I can get the (x,y,z) coordinate as well as the surface normal of the user selected point. But I can't figure out how to obtain the four corners of the rectangle around the selected point. (Assume that the selected point already lies on a plane) I am trying to implement it in PCL with C++. I am fairly new at PCL, so any help or pointing me towards the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some more info? And maybe some images of the cloud? I am not sure what you mean by "how to obtain the four corners of the rectangle around the selected point." Are you looking for the corners of a plane on which the point lies? If so, what plane?

Comment: @brad I have a cloud of two walls. I want the user to be able to click a point on these wall and the program to fit a rectangle of a known size (you can assume any values you want to) aligned to the wall on which the user clicked/selected the point. But I also need the coordinates of the four corner of the said rectangle that will be aligned to the user selected point in 3D space (thus having a new set of values, since the rectangle will be rotated around for the alignment.). The surface normal is also known for the point clicked by the user. The point clicked will be the center of the rect.